# Setup Bootstrapper's output(.exe) file running on windows7 but does not work on windows Xp

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Here is the wix Bundle.wxs code that I am using to get the output setup(.exe). The output setup.exe is working fine with windows7 but does not show any message or progress in windows Xp . It does nothing. Any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
   <Bundle Name="A" Version="4.0.0.0" Manufacturer="ABC, Inc." UpgradeCode="1EB9EC76-9E5F-4471-B522-314A62518A80">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="LicenseFilePath" LogoFile="logo.ico" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40ClientWeb" />
      <MsiPackage Compressed="yes" SourceFile="sourceMsiPath" Vital="yes" />
     </Chain>
   </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Is there any log file in your temp directory? If so what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WixStandardBootstrapperApplication cannot load ico file as it needs GDI+ on XP.

```
LogoFile="logo.ico"
```

change it to

```
LogoFile="logo.png"
```

and it should work.